# How can I expose plugin functions to docpad partials?

Tags: plugins, tagging, partials, docpad

tldr; Is there a way to expose functions defined in one plugin for another plugin to use?

I'm trying to use the tagging plugin (https://github.com/rantecki/docpad-plugin-tagging) within a partial.

I have a Jade partial setup as follows:

```
.post-tags
  | Posted in 
  each tag in tags
    a(href=getTagUrl(tag))= tag + ' '
```

where `getTagUrl` is a function defined by the tagging plugin. The problem is that the partial has no knowledge and this partial does not render.

Answer (score 2):

As v2.8.0+ of the partials plugin now includes the template data by default (you don't have to manually specify it's inclusion anymore), try running `docpad update` in your project's root directory and trying again. Otherwise, we'll probably have to see the source code of your project to help isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's because partial do not have access by default to templateData, the object holding the getTagUrl helper. You have to pass it explicitly to the partial.

Here's a similar answer provided for the eco templating language :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16631649/232943

Comment: For what it's worth, the partials plugin v2.8.0+ now includes template data by default. I've updated the answer you've linked to reflect this. Thanks! :)